# Permutation on the set of restricted permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, permutations, examples-counterexamples

Let $S$ be the set of restricted permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ where $1$ can be permuted to $1,2$ and $n$ can permuted to $n,n-1$ and $i$ can be permuted to $i-1,i,i+1$ for $2\leq i\leq n-1$.

Let $f:S\to S$ be a bijection. Let $\underbrace{f\circ f\circ \cdots f(x)}_{\text{m times}}=x$ be called the orbit of $x$ under $f$ for some $x\in S$.

> I am trying to find a bijection $f$ with an orbit as large as possible. I am not sure how to go about finding that. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I have a bit question: are you supposing that $f:S\rightarrow S$ is a bijection such that $$\underbrace{f\circ\dots\circ f}_{\text{m times}}(x)=x$$ for any $x\in S$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro That would be ideal. But even if $m$ is large for most $x\in S$, that works for me.

Comment: What you claim is interesting: however, I do not see how the square function $f(x):=\sqrt{x}$ could be such that $f^m=\text{id}$ for any $m\in\Bbb N$...perhaps cloud you indicate this such $m$ for the square function?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Sorry, are you asking me? I did not mention $f(x):=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for you.

Comment: Oh yeah, you did not mentioned the square function but you said that if $m$ is large for $x\in S$ then the statement works for you, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I don't understand the question. I am trying to find a bijection $f$ on $S$ such that $m$ is large.

Comment: Ok, a possible idea: $|S|=F_n$ the $n-$th Fibonacci number. What if you enumerate the permutations(say $x_i$) there and use Zeckendorf representation to send $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ getting a cycle of length $n$(so $m=F_n$). Would you be interested in the definition of the bijection recursively? Or you want a nice close expression?

Comment: @Phicar Oh wow, I didn't know that $|S|=F_n$. Sorry, I don't know the Zeckendorf representation. A closed form expression for $f$ would be great if possible.

Comment: @manifolded Yeah, call $a_n =|S|$ then clearly $a_i=i$ for $i<3$ and if you fix $1$ then you get $a_{n-1}$ and if you send  $1->2$ then you get $a_{n-2}$ and hence $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. I have no idea how(or if it is possible) to write that in a closed way. The Zeckendorf representation(a unique way to write any number as sum of fibonacci's) would tell you which permutation is the one at position $i$.

Comment: @Phicar Thanks. I can see that when we fix $1$, then we get $a_{n-1}$ because that is the number of ways in which we can permute the remaining $n-1$ numbers. But if we send $1\to 2$, then I don't understand why we get $a_{n-2}$? I know that your claim is correct though.

Comment: @manifolded Cause you form the cycle $(1,2)$ and then you have to deal with the rest $n-2$ objects.Notice that, by the comment I made before understanding the question, every cycle of $f\in S$ is at most $2$.

Comment: @Phicar Understood! Thanks.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{Fib}(n)$ the answer (cycle through all the permitted permutations) or are you looking for an answer like $g(\operatorname{Fib}(n))$  where $g(x)$ is [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) so the order of the group of bijections?   So for example with $n=5$ you get $g(\operatorname{Fib}(5))=g(8)=15$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the best case you can hope for is that $m=|S|$, namely that all permutations in $S$ are in one big orbit. Here is an $f$ which achieves this.

From the comments, you know that a permutation $\pi$ is in $S$ if and only if $S$ the cycle structure of $\pi$ only has fixed points and transpositions, and all transpositions are of the form $(i\;\;i+1)$, switching adjacent elements. For completeness, the proof is this. If $\pi(n)=n$, then by induction, $\pi$ restricted to $\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ also has the form described. If $\pi(n)=n-1$, then you must have $\pi(n-1)=n$, since only $n-1$ and $n$ can map to $n$, and we similarly conclude by induction that $\pi$ restricted to $\{1,\dots,n-2\}$ has the claimed form.

Such a permutation can be uniquely represented as an ordered sequence of ones and twos whose total is $n$. For example,
$$
(1\;2)(3)(4)(5\;6)(7\;8)(9)\quad \iff\quad 2,1,1,2,2,1
$$
I will define $f:S\to S$ in terms of these sequences of ones and twos.

> Let $s\in S$. To compute $f(s)$,
>
> - Find the rightmost $1$ in $s$ which is not at the right end. If no such $1$ exists, then $s=2,2,\dots,2$ or $s=2,2,\dots,2,1$, and we define $f(s)=1,1,\dots,1$.
>
>   - If that $1$ has a $1$  to its right, then delete both $1$'s, and put a $2$ in their place.
>   - If that $1$ is has a $2$ to its right, then switch that $1$ and $2$.
> - Finally, find all $2$'s to the right of the change just made, and replace each of them with the substring $1,1$.

More succinctly, $f(s)$ is the next string after $s$ in lexicographic order, unless $s$ is the last in this order, in which case $f(s)$ is the earliest string. Here is an example of the complete orbit when $n=6$.

| Step | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $1111\color{red}{11}$ |
| 2 | $111\color{red}{12}$ |
| 3 | $11\color{red}{12}1$ |
| 4 | $112\color{red}{11}$ |
| 5 | $1\color{red}{12}2$ |
| 6 | $121\color{red}{11}$ |
| 7 | $12\color{red}{12}$ |
| 8 | $\color{red}{12}21$ |
| 9 | $211\color{red}{11}$ |
| 10 | $21\color{red}{12}$ |
| 11 | $2\color{red}{12}{1}$ |
| 12 | $22\color{red}{11}$ |
| 13 | $222$ |
| 14 | $111111$ |